# Using Lightning headphones in my Dell laptop

Tags: iphone, lightning

I have an iPhone 7 with Lightning headphones. I got a connecting adapter to use 3.5mm compatible headphones on an iPhone 7. But, is it possible to use these Lightning headphones on the 3.5mm jack of my Dell laptop? I tried Googling and haven't found any converter/adapter.

Comment: Basically, you're looking for the reverse of [this cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMX62AM/A/lightning-to-35-mm-headphone-jack-adapter). Apple doesn't sell it, and people [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7661700?start=0&tstart=0) indicate it would cause a loss of signal quality.

Answer (score 3):

You would need a USB to Lightening adapter for that. The newer Dell laptops do come with USB-C port adapters.

Answer (score -1):

The lightning to 3.5mm jack adapter that comes with the iPhone 7 should work with the Dell laptop and the iPhone. That adapter was constructed to work with the standard 3.5mm headphone jack that most devices use. I've yet to see a special 3.5mm jack, just because it was/is an industry standard.

Comment: Doesn't the lightning to 3.5mm adapter that comes with the phone go the wrong direction? (as in, the 3.5mm from the headphones plugs into it, and it plugs into the lightning port; whereas the question is wanting to plug a lightning jack from the headphones into an adaptor that can then plug into the 3.5mm jack on the Dell.)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I understand now. What your need is a reverse lightning to 3.5mm adapter. That hasn't been made yet, plus converting lightning (digital) to 3.5mm (analog) is very complex. Its almost like a downgrade with the tech. The only way that would be logically possible without ruining audio quality is to hook up lightning to a male USB adapter then you can use the common female USB to 3.5mm adapter. I haven't tried it but the parts are out there,